# collect multiple datatables in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

since I'm very new in C#, i wanted to know which is a good option for multiple datatables management. I have a project with 100 datatables circa (let's say similar to each other but different in columns number).  I don't know how to collect them, do I need an array of datatables? (ps: datatables are created dinamically at runtime and the number of them may vary)
thank you in advance

Comment: thanks to all for all answers, now i know what to do. i'm still getting confused tough, because n addition to your suggested code (which works fine for me), in visual studio I see ad add->new item->dataset and it create a whole bunch of files like a .xsd and others. is that a dataset too? it's a different way of implementing it? or it's related to other functionalities? thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With this class you can collect many DataTables and work with them. DataTables are stored in the [DataSet.Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.dataset.tables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

A Dataset is like a database ... containing many tables with relationsships an so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dataset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx), which itself is a collection of DataTable objects. so you can add/mange/delete datatables from it. DataSets can hold multiple tables and you can define relationships between those tables.

Let  `dataContainer` be a dataset defined as below:

```
DataSet dataContainer = new DataSet();
```

Consider the methods `addtableToSet()` which will show [how to add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/as4zy2kc(v=vs.110).aspx) datatables to the DataSet, and `RemoveTableFromSet()` will show you [how to remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/sdc233k4(v=vs.110).aspx) them based on name.

```
public void addtableToSet()
{
    DataTable tableA = new DataTable("TableA");
    DataTable tableB = new DataTable("TableB");
    DataTable tableC = new DataTable("TableC");
    dataContainer.Tables.Add(tableA);
    dataContainer.Tables.Add(tableB);
    dataContainer.Tables.Add(tableC);
    dataContainer.Tables.Add(new DataTable("TableD"));
}

public void RemoveTableFromSet(string tableName)
{
    dataContainer.Tables.Remove(tableName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with the datatable once they are generated.

You could keep them all in a dictionary if you can have a unique name for each datatable.

```
DataTable GeneratedTable1;
DataTable GeneratedTable2;

Dictionary<string, DataTable> DataTableDictionary = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();

// Adding the tables to the Dictionary
DataTableDictionary.Add("MyUniqueName1", GeneratedTable1);
DataTableDictionary.Add("MyUniqueName2", GeneratedTable2);

// Lookup a DataTable     
DataTable MyLookedUpDataTable = DataTableDictionary["MyUniqueName1"];
```